# Sample Weight vs. Down Sampling for Handling Imbalanced Data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science

Suppose you have an imbalanced dataset. Without considering to generate new data to it, how can you handle it efficiently. I know we can use sample weight or down sampling. However, between these two, I am not sure which to choose. Also, suppose you need to build a classification model on this imbalanced data, how will these two techniques influence the model performances differently?

Answer (score 2):

It totally depends upon that if you down sample how much of data observations do you have left, and how efficiently the down sampled class is able to accommodate the variety of the class down sampled.
for example, you have class 1 which consists of 100 observations and class 2  which contains 2000 observations (Class 1 is ~ 5%). Then downsampling wont make sense as there wont be enough data observations present to effetively implement a model. 100 observations are very less. The model would have high training errors.

But if you have Class 1 which has 100,000 observations and Class 2 having 2,000,000 (5% again) then it still make sense to downsample as you have enough observations to train model.

So the answer totally depends on the type of data you have. I personally would go with SMOTE. Hope this helps.